# Questions about blockchain

Tags: blockchain

I am a newbie with blockchain and I have a few questions please, I've already googled but I have misunderstood some points:

1. How data is stored in the block in blockchain? in bit format, text or
   other?
2. What is the benefit of the block less?
3. Can we store in the same block unrelated transactions?
4. How to explain censorship-resistant for blockchain?

Comment: What do you mean by unrelated transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Generally speaking, not strict about Ethereum blockchain, data are stored in any useful format, without prejudice. The block, usually, is comprehensive of addresses, code, link which are often expressed in binary format for compactness.

3) Of course yes, unrelated transactions in one block is the normality. For instance transaction made by user A on contract B reside in the block togheter with transactions made by user C on smart contract D and togheter with transactions made by user F involving user E and Z, and so on. The only relationship being that of the time interval in which they have been finalized.